# Create an interactive sequence diagram in HTML / JavaScript with non-image output

Tags: java, javascript, html, sequence-diagram

I want to create a representation of a sequence diagram on a HTML/JavaScript page. And I want the visualization to be interactive. E.g. I want to be able to click on each of the objects/life-lines/etc in the diagram and see the actual source code. However, all of the tools and libraries that I found for generating sequence diagrams return an image which of course cannot be edited or interacted with. Does anyone know of a library that I could use that lets me have access to the inner elements of the sequence diagram and lets me extend them as objects or HTML elements?

Thanks

PS. The representation can be made by Java as well. I just thought it'd be easier to show the features I want using JavaScript but I also appreciate the answers regarding Java!

Answer (score 0):

[JS Sequence Diagrams](https://github.com/bramp/js-sequence-diagrams/) sounds like a good fit; it renders directly into SVG on the page.